# Make a Google+ post visible to all users but invisible to Google search

Tags: google-plus, google-search, privacy

I know that the Public circle is like a free-for-all and people can find your posts for the Public circle using search engines. I'd like my posts to be visible to only G+ users.

How do I set my posts to only be found by those in Google+ and not allow those via Google web search?

Answer (score 1):

By default, your profile will appear in Google search results. You can change your profile settings at any time if you don't want Google and other search engines to index your profile.

**To change your profile settings:**

- Place your cursor in the top left corner for the Google+ main menu.
- Click Settings: https://www.google.com/settings/plus

In the Profile section, find the "Help others discover my profile in search results" option:

- Uncheck Help others discover my profile in search results if you don't want search engines to index your profile.

*If you choose not to have search engines index your profile, your profile itself won't appear in Google search results.*

However:

- Your profile will still remain visible to anyone with your profile URL.
- Other pages and content (including websites, blogs, and Google products such as Picasa Web) that link to your profile can still appear in search results on Google and other search engines.

Changes you make to your profile visibility setting may be reflected across search engines at different times, depending on when each search engine crawls your profile page.

You may be suggested to people who have you in their Contacts as a person to add to their Circles.

I hope this helps!